# PHP MVC Design issue

Tags: php, undefined

I'm trying to build MVC pattern using OOP PHP. Please read the rest of the post to understand what I want exactly.

This is the homepage controller which extends the main controller

```
class Home extends Controller {

    function __construct () {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index () {
        $this->load->model("test");
        $this->test->get_all();
        $data = array (
            'name' => "Amr",
            'age' =>24
        );
        $this->load->view("home_view",$data);
    }

}
```

The Main Controller looks like this and extends loader class:

```
class Controller extends Loader {
    public $load;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load = new Loader();
    }
}
```

The Loader class which has the problem looks like this

```
class Loader {

    public $Error;

    function __construct(){
        $this->Error = new Error();
    }

    public function model($Modelname){
        $this->$Modelname = $Modelname;
        if (file_exists("models/".$Modelname.".php")){
            require_once $Modelname . ".php";
            $this->$Modelname = new $Modelname;
        }else{
            $this->Error->Not_found();
        }
    }

    public function view($Viewname,$data=NULL){
        if(is_array($data)){
            extract($data);
        }
        if (file_exists("views/".$Viewname.".php")){
            require_once $Viewname . ".php";
        }else{
            $this->Error->Not_found();
        }
    }

    public function helper($helper) {
        if (file_exists("helpers/".$helper.".php")){
            require_once $helper . ".php";
            $this->$helper = new $helper;
        }else{
            $this->Error->Not_found();
        }
    }

}
```

What I need to do is to be able FROM HOMEPAGE Controller to do something like this:

```
$this->load->model("someModel"); // model name is test
$this->someModel->someMethodInModel(); // the model method is get_all()
// and the same for helper
$this->load->helper("someHelper");
$this->someHelper->someMethodInHelper();
```

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT: The error that I'm getting when doing this is:**

> Notice: Undefined property: Home::$test
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_all() on a non-object

NOTE: the model name is `test` and the model method is `get_all()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function model($Modelname){
$this->$Modelname = $Modelname;
if (file_exists("models/".$Modelname.".php")){
require_once $Modelname . ".php";
$this->$Modelname = new $Modelname;
```

What do you need help with? With your current code you can do

```
$this->load->model("someModel");
$this->someModel->someMethodInModel();
// and the same for helper
$this->load->helper("someHelper");
$this->someHelper->someMethodInHelper();
```

in your Home controller. I just tried it out myself. What errors do you get? What's not working properly?

Comment: I made edit on the post John and thats what i`m get , thanks alot for your time and hope you can help me

Comment: I edited the code the current code is what im using its same except two lines added to the index method in the home controller

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would put a "load()" method into my controller which would call the "loader" class and store the new model/helper/view into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is, your loader creates an instance of a model as a member of the `Loader` class, and not your controller class.

Comment: It's a scope issue, and one of the fundamentals of object-orientated programming. Your `Loader` class is instantiating a model, and adding it as a member of that class, not your controller class calling your `load()` method. So to access your model from your controller, you'd need to do something like `$this->load->someModel->someMethodInModel();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if your base controller extends Loader then there is no reason  use it like property

```
class Controller extends Loader {
    public $load;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load = new Loader();
    }
}
```

change it to

```
class Controller extends Loader {

}
```

another way is to use magic method hook http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

```
class Controller {
    public $load;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load = new Loader();
    }

    function __get($modelName){
       return $this->load->$modelName;
    }


}
```